# Using property as edge label during relationship creation

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4j query:

```
UNWIND [{s:"a"}, {s:"b"}] AS x
WITH x

MATCH (y:Y {b:"hi"}), (z:Z {b:"hi"}) 
WITH y, z

MERGE (y)-[:x.s]->(z)
```

The idea is to use x.s as the label of the edge between y and z. But this throws the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '.': expected an
>   identifier character, whitespace, '|', a length specification, a
>   property map or ']' (line 7, column 14 (offset: 101)) "MERGE
>   (y)-[:x.s]->(z)" ^

What would be the appropiate query to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you lose `x` in your second `WITH` command. Secondly, you cannot create a relationship with `MERGE` or `CREATE` when the relationship type is actually the value of a variable. You should use `apoc.create.relationship` instead:

```
UNWIND [{s:"a"}, {s:"b"}] AS x
WITH x

MATCH (y:Y {b:"hi"}), (z:Z {b:"hi"}) 
WITH y, z, x

CALL apoc.create.relationship(y, x.s, {},z) YIELD rel
RETURN *
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I'll select yours as best. Out of curiosity, is this the only way to achieve this (using the create.relationship procedure)? Also, what goes in the {} in the procedure? Is it the relation properties?

Comment: Thank you. Yes because you cannot parametrize the type  of relationships when you create them. AFIK this is the only way to do it. Do you have a particular requirement for which you don’t like this solution? And yes you are correct about {}.

Answer (score 1):

I found this can be done using the `apoc.create.relationship` procedure:

```
UNWIND [{s:"c"}, {s:"d"}] AS x
WITH x

MATCH (y:Y {b:"hi"}), (z:Z {b:"hi"}) 
WITH y, z, x

CALL apoc.create.relationship(y, x.s, {}, z) YIELD rel
RETURN y,z
```

I will leave the question open for a bit to see if someone can come up with a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/), you should see that this query requires fewer DB hits:

```
MATCH (y:Y {b:"hi"}), (z:Z {b:"hi"})
UNWIND ["c", "d"] AS x
CALL apoc.create.relationship(y, x, {}, z) YIELD rel
RETURN y,z
```

Also, you should create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:X(b)` and `:Z(b)` to improve the performance.

Comment: The two differences I see is the fact that "c" and "d" are no longer values of properties, just values in a list. I also see WITH is not being used in this query. If there's something else I'm missing, can you explain how is this query different from the previously suggested one and why does it require fewer DB hits please?

Comment: The things I used were: (1) Intuition - it seemed possible that the `MATCH` could be executed twice if the `UNWIND` came first, so I swapped the 2 clauses and used `PROFILE` to check and saw a difference (although not necessarily due to what I expected). (2) Simplification (which often also simplifies the generated plan) - again, `PROFILE` showed the "c"/"d" simplification reduced DB hits. NOTE: Your results can differ from mine, especially if you are using a different neo4j version, so you should always run `PROFILE` yourself to check.